# Personalizar el nuevo mini reproductor de Chrome

Tags: html5

estaba en youtube escuchando musica y me acorde que chrome puso un nuevo mini reproductor en la pestaña de navegacion y este aparecia de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aqui]

y yo quise integrar eso en mi pagina cuando vez un video (el que se ponga la mini del video en el reproductor de chrome), pero e buscado y no encuentro nada relacionado, creí que esa imagen era de la etiqueta `<meta property="og:image">` pero no funciono con eso, espero me puedan ayudar con esto

Comment: Quizás sea esta API de javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSession

Comment: Aquí de tejo un ejemplo https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/video.html